# Postman crashes when running collection with large response, but only when request has a TEST

Tags: postman

I have a small (2 request) collection that crashes Postman under certain specific, confusing conditions.  The collection is as follows:

1. A GET request obtains a set of integer identifiers from one service and, in its tests, converts those integers to objects.
2. A POST request takes the objects and passes them to another service which responds with a significant amount of structured JSON for each of the ids.

The second request, the POST, causes Postman to crash and immediately close if *both* of the following are true:

1. The number of IDs is 1400 or higher (the real number is between 1300 and 1400).
2. There is some code associated in the test for the POST request.

If either of those conditions is not met, the request succeeds. However, *it does not matter what code is in the test*.  Even code that does not touch the response (like the single line `console.log("hello, world");`) the presence of anything at all in the test causes Postman to crash.

When running the collection from the Postman desktop client, the client simply closes.  When running the collection from the Postman CLI tool, I get:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000E69A3FC9F0
 1: 00007FF719F6848F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114399
 2: 00007FF719E8467F std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<+65023
 3: 00007FF71AB63892 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF71A6E76F5 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF71A5A7B72 v8::Context::GetIsolate+16706
 6: 00007FF71A41B361 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+26913
 7: 00007FF71A8BA0B1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
 8: 000002AF1C13431E
```

PS: I know about the setting for large response sizes and have it set to 0 (unlimited) in the Postman desktop client.

Comment: use dothttp https://docs.dothttp.dev/